SSL certificate for second level subdomain and wildcard subdomain
I have the following problem: I want to secure my structure with SSL, but certbot tells me the domains I am adding to the cert are redundant.
I want to add the following (sub)domains to the cert:

a.foo.com

*.a.foo.com


b.foo.com
*.foo.com

Certbot keeps complaining about a.foo.com being included in the subdomain wildcard.
The only solution I can think of, and that more or less works, is to have the  following SANs in the certificate:

*.foo.com

*.a.foo.com



Is this the correct way to do it?

Your current solution with only the wildcard certificates (*.foo.com and *.a.foo.com) is the correct way to handle this situation.
Here's why:
A wildcard certificate (*.a.foo.com) inherently covers any subdomain under "a.foo.com," including a.foo.com itself. Including both is redundant!
Including only the wildcards achieves the same security for all subdomains while keeping the certificate cleaner. So, stick with your current approach of using just the wildcard certificates in your SSL request.
Certbot shouldn't complain anymore, and your server will be secured for all the intended domains.

Okay, thanks! I didn't know if this was common practice, but it seems like the (most) reasonable way of solving this problem. It is a shame, as I can't explicitly mention the SANs of the most important subdomains, but being a wildcard cert, it doesn't make any sense to do so.

No, a certificate wildcard *.a.foo.com does NOT cover a.foo.com. But *.foo.com DOES cover a.foo.com so the result works.

You are absolutely correct! I apologize for the mistake in my previous responses.
Wildcard certificates like ".a.foo.com" don't cover the root domain (a.foo.com).
But your use of ".foo.com" is correct. It secures all subdomains under "foo.com", including "a.foo.com" and "b.foo.com".
